# Order type of a sum ($\bigcup$) of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

A quick question. Is $$\textrm{ot}(\bigcup\limits_{\gamma <\lambda}\alpha_{\gamma})=\bigcup\limits_{\gamma <\lambda}\textrm{ot}(\alpha_{\gamma})?$$
where $\textrm{ot}$ stands for the order type (and $\lambda$ can be limit ordinal or not).

It seems like a nice property which can be very much false, but I don't know neither how to prove it nor can I find a counterexample.

Comment: Is your $\operatorname{ot}$ operation not the identity on ordinals? In that case it does nothing on either side of your equation (a union of ordinals is always an ordinal), and then no difference is left. If you _don't_ have $\operatorname{ot}\alpha=\alpha$ in general, then you need to describe in more detail exactly what that operation does.

Comment: The $\alpha_\gamma$ are ordinals? If so, each is its own order type, and their union is *its* own order type, so the statement is true.

Comment: Oh my gosh, such a stupid question, I'm sorry I must be very tired.

Comment: A more interesting question: Given sets of ordinals $A_0,A_1$ of order type $\alpha_0,\alpha_1$, what are the possible order types of $A_0\cup A_1$?

Answer (score 0):

... Something funny has just happened to me: I believed for many years that, if $a$ and $b$ are subsets of a well-ordered set $x$, then $$\textrm{type}(a \cup b) \leqslant \textrm{type(a)} + \textrm{type}(b)$$

However, this is not correct (and I have should know better $\ldots$). I was talking to a student, trying to prove the above inequality, and something was not right ("what happens if the set $a \cup b$ has a maximum, and such maximum is an element of $a$ ?"). Indeed: the true statement is $$\textrm{type}(a \cup b) \leqslant \textrm{type(a)} + \textrm{type}(b) + 1$$

To check that the first inequality is incorrect, you may consider $x = \omega.2 + 1$, $a = \omega \cup \{\omega.2\}$ and $b = x \setminus a$.

(To prove the correct inequality, one has just to proceed with induction on the type of $a \cup b$, this isn't difficult.)

Edited: The second inequality is also incorrect !!! See comments below of @asatzhh.

Comment: This inequality is not correct as well. Thinking about $x=\omega\cdot 2+2$ and the same $b$. Then right side is $\omega\cdot 2+1$

Comment: The second inequality (the one I have declared as the correct one) is $\textrm{type}(a \cup b) \leqslant \textrm{type}(a) + \textrm{type}(b) + 1$. If $x = \omega.2 + 2$, $a = \omega \cup \{\omega.2\}$ and $b = x \setminus a$, then $\textrm{type}(x) = \textrm{type}(a \cup b) = x = \omega.2 + 2$, whereas $\textrm{type}(a) = \omega + 1 = \textrm{type}(b)$; and $(\omega + 1) + (\omega + 1) + 1 = \omega.2 + 2$.

Comment: I mean the same $b$, so your $a$ is now $\omega\cup\{\omega\cdot2,\omega\cdot2+1\}$, hence $\text{type}(a)+\text{type}(b)=\omega+2+\omega=\omega\cdot2$. In general you can extend it using Cantor normal form of $\text{type}(a\cup b)$ and $\text{type}(a)+\text{type}(b)$ should be larger than the dominant term of the Cantor normal form.

Comment: Ops, I see, you are right. I will edit my answer. Thanks !